# Is there any Executor connecting to Broker?

Tags: multithreading, scala

I need to execute the same task many times as much as possible within given milliseconds. So I made it using scala.actors.threadpool.Executors as following code.

```
import actors.threadpool.{TimeUnit, Future, Executors}
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object TaskRepeater {

  def repeat(task: Runnable, millisecs: Long): Int = {
    val exector = Executors.newCachedThreadPool
    val remover = Executors.newCachedThreadPool

    val queue = ListBuffer[Future]()
    def removeDone() {
      (queue filter (_.isDone)) foreach { f =>
        queue.remove(queue indexOf f)
      }
    }

    val lock = new EasyLock()

    val maxQueueSize = scala.collection.parallel.availableProcessors

    val queueAvaiable = lock.mkCondition(queue.size < maxQueueSize)

    var cnt = 0

    val start = System.nanoTime()

    while(System.nanoTime() - start < millisecs * 1000000) {
      lock {
        queueAvaiable.waitUntilFulfiled()

        cnt += 1
        val r = exector.submit(task)
        queue += r

        remover.submit(runneble {
          r.get()
          lock {
            removeDone()
            queueAvaiable.signalIfFulfilled()
          }
        })
      }
    }

    exector.shutdown()
    remover.shutdown()

    assert(exector.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

    cnt
  }

  def runneble(f: => Unit) = new Runnable {
    def run() {
      f
    }
  }
}

import actors.threadpool.locks.{Condition, ReentrantLock}

class EasyLock {
  val lock = new ReentrantLock

  def mkCondition(f: => Boolean): EasyCondition = {
    new EasyCondition(lock.newCondition(), f)
  }

  def apply(f: => Unit) {
    lock.lock()
    try {
      f
    } finally {
      lock.unlock()
    }
  }
}

class EasyCondition(c: Condition, condition: => Boolean) {

  def waitUntilFulfiled(f: => Unit) {
    while (!condition) {
      c.await()
    }
    f
  }

  def signalAllIfFulfilled() {
    if (condition) c.signalAll()
  }

  def signalIfFulfilled() {
    if (condition) c.signal()
  }
}
```

But this is a bit complex. Instead, I think, Broker of Twitter and some Executor which connects with the Broker and sends a finished task to the Broker, if exists, could make it easier.

The following is a pseudo code

```
val b = new Broker
val e = new Executor // connects with the broker anyway
e.runTask
val o = b.recv
o.sync() // wait until the task finishes
```

Is there any Executor like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you may be able to use `FuturePool` like this:

```
val b = new Broker[T]
val futurePool = FuturePool.defaultPool // or some other pool
futurePool(task).onSuccess { b ! _ }
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey, This is what I want. Forgive me not to upvote, since I have too little reputation to do so :)

Comment: @yakamoto You can still accept the answer, I believe (click the checkmark under the votes).